# How to make ubuntu understand a windows-style folder path as a folder on windows partition?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, paths, alias

I have ubuntu and Win7 on dual boot.
On windows, a use a program that is set to save things on a given windows folder (like "D:\some folder").
On ubuntu, I can run this exact same program (it's not a linux version of the program, it's really the same program located on my windows partition that I can run from ubuntu).

My problem is that when I run it on ubuntu, the program can't save things because it's set to save on "D:\some folder", which ubuntu doesn't recognize as a valid path. This folder's path on ubuntu is "/media/D/some folder"

Is there a way to make ubuntu understand "D:\some folder" as a synonym/alias of "/media/D/some folder" so that when I use this program on ubuntu it's able to save things in the same folder as it does when run on windows? It's really bothersome to have to change the path every time I run this program on the other OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to get Ubuntu to understand Windows File Paths. You can however install Wine and run the program in Wine to get Windows File Paths. Wine is a sort of a Windows Translation Layer to Run Windows Programs in a Unix environment(translating Windows-based requests into something Unix can understand). Whether this works depends on the program you're trying to run.

http://www.winehq.org/

Comment: I think the OP is already using Wine - it is impossible to run native Windows executables on Linux directly.

Comment: Yeah I was confused about that too. But if he was then he should be getting Windows Paths in the program. I'm thinking the Program is either Java or Python.

Comment: Furthermore the path in wine will not be the same as in windows. On my system z: in equivalent to / in linux. So d: would still be z:\media\drive_label

Comment: @ToDo You're right, but you can use Symbolic Links and tweaks in the "Drives" tab to get the paths to match up. I've done similar things before.

Comment: @jap, I'm very sorry for not telling the program I'm using. Since I'm new to linux I did it on purpose to get a more generic answer, so that the knowledge may also be useful in the future if I run on similar situations. I often see questions that are so specific that are rarely useful. And it worked! Now I know of Wine and Symbolic Links! As for the program, it's actually a firefox extension. I'm sharing the same profile under both OSs and some extensions are set to save things with win-style paths, so i can't use them on ubuntu unless I change the path every time.

Comment: @Graubis Ah I see. Yeah the way around your problem would be to install and run Firefox inside Wine. Of course this may cause other problems down the road related to integration with Ubuntu, but if you're fine with that go right ahead.

Comment: may I suggest some form of intelligent syncing? firefox sync +siphon is perhaps worth a try.

Comment: @Mahesh That doesn't solve his problem. His problem isn't syncing, it's the differences between the two platforms' file systems and the changing location of his files between the two.

Comment: If I have the desired extensions on both platforms, a simple sync of the files those extensions use or perhaps simple symlinking hackery with proper initial configuration for the extensions should work painlessly. To be precise, his problem isn't with file system at all. Its with the difference between how they handle the paths. Its with the path separator being different.

Comment: @Mahesh I know it is, and I already stated that before and his possible solution. All I said to you was that Firefox Sync doesn't fix and isn't related to his problem.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not possible to do it properly, there is a funny hack. You can create a symlink named "D:" (names with : are allowed on most filesystems outside of Windows) and point it to the location you want. The problem is the location of the symlink. If you put it in your home directory and it coincides with current working directory, it may work. You can also copy it somewhere which is a different working directory of your need. I think it's also possible to enable case-insensitivity in ext4 FS so both "d:" and "D:" would work (otherwise you would need to create both).